# sql server - selecting numeric values and merging columns into one

Tags: sql-server

I am selecting values in two columns.
Suppose I have the code and results as follow:

```
 SELECT 
(SELECT REPLACE(STUFF(column1, 1, PATINDEX('% '+REPLICATE('[0-9]', 5) + '%', column1), ''), ')', '')) as tablename ,
(SELECT REPLACE(STUFF(column2, 1, PATINDEX('% '+REPLICATE('[0-9]', 5) + '%', column2), ''), ')', '')) as tablename
 FROM table

tablename             tablename
12345                 qwertyuiop
67891                 asdfghjkl
zxcvbnm               98765
```

how can I make those two columns from above result into this result below? I tried to use union (all) but it doesn't work.

```
tablename
12345
678910
987654
```

Comment: Search for `ISNULL` or `COALESCE`.

Comment: It should be a single column, not two. The query will return one column called "tablename", not two.

Comment: the question is really unclear... Provide some real example, this won't help

Comment: @404notfound what version of sql server do you have? With 2012+ you can use `TRYCONVERT()` because you need to select only integer type values

Comment: How do you come up with the result?

Comment: @404notfound as an answer below, I would try that `ISNUMERIC()` select, that could fit for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want only numeric values from your cols you can use the query below:

```
SELECT CASE 
      WHEN ISNUMERIC ((SELECT REPLACE(STUFF(column1, 1, PATINDEX('% '+REPLICATE('[0-9]', 13) + '%', column1), ''), ')', '')))  <> 1 
       THEN (SELECT REPLACE(STUFF(column1, 1, PATINDEX('% '+REPLICATE('[0-9]', 13) + '%', column1), ''), ')', ''))  
       ELSE (SELECT REPLACE(STUFF(column2, 1, PATINDEX('% '+REPLICATE('[0-9]', 13) + '%', column2), ''), ')', '')) 
       END tablename 
FROM table
```

Comment: it shows errors Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ELSE'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are trying to merge two columns from two different tables. try this:

```
select col1 from table1
UNION
select col2 from table2
```

Use union instead of union all. Make sure col1 and col2 are of same types.It works. Let me know if any issues

Comment: u can try as:

(select col1 as test from table1 
union
select col2 as test from table1) T
where isnumeric(T.test + '.0e0') = 1

Once you get the merging of two columns, you can filter the numeric values from single columns. Let me know if it works.